# update data in Callback

Tags: c++, callback, c++builder

I am trying to develop an application with **C++ builder xe**  using some `DLL` communication.
In the DLLs I use a callback which is implemented in `myClass`:

myClass.h

```
static void CALLBACK CallbackAsynchEvent(unsigned char* Data);
```

myClass.cpp

```
    void CALLBACK CallbackAsynchEvent(unsigned char* Data)
{
// use Data to update a variable membre of myClass
}
```

When I try to update an object XXXX of `myClass` using Data I obtain `: "E2451 Undefined symbol XXXX"`

Can you help me find the problem?

Comment: you should probably post some more code, but maybe you are trying to access a non-static member of myClass, which you cannot do in a static function?

Comment: I think that this is the problem.
And I beleive that the solution is wrapping a C++ method into a C callback API.
Anyone know how to perform that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem by wrapping a C++ method into a C callback API:

Here is an example for those they need help:

```
void myClass::vDoSomething(unsigned char* Data)
{
   // work todo in the callback
}

void CALLBACK CallbackAsynchEvt(unsigned char* Data, void *ptT)
{
   static_cast<myClass*>(ptT)->vDoSomthing(Data);
}

// the function membre of myClass where the Pointer is passed:

Start(CallbackAsynchEvt, static_cast<void *>(this));
```